# What is meant by 'dancing on this'?

Tags: american-english

> Move fast baby, don't be slow
>
> Step aside, reload, time to go
>
> I can't seem to control
>
> All this rage that's inside me
>
> Hold it fast, they've been dancing on this
>
> Branded by fire on the abyss
>
> Red hot temper, I just can't resist
>
> All this vengeance inside me

I am not sure I understand what dancing on this mean? Dancing on the rage? And fire on the abyss? Does it mean fire that's burning on the abyss?

Comment: Song/rap lyrics are often written for the sake of a good rhyme rather than to make perfect sense. 'It' probably refers to 'rage' and 'this' may also refer to 'rage'. Who 'they' are I don't know. The only antecedent for 'this' that I can see is 'rage', so someone has been dancing on the singer's rage. (Whatever that means)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for [literature.se], being about interpretation of specific song lyrics in context rather than the meaning of an English phrase.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From [Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/zn4nn5y#sdbpqoq) i find this senseof dancing on someone:

dance on someone, ...someone’s face)(US black)

> 1. to hit in the face.
> 2. to kick in the face.

ie .. to spite.

Branded by fire on the abyss:

> His rage is branded into him by the fires (events) of the abyss (this
>   chaos).

Of course, literary license can have variations by dancing on someone or something his heard in AmE.

Comment: but she says 'dancing on this' and not 'dancing on him'

Comment: figurative  ... dancing on him, or the rage, or his rage and the whole ball o' wax!